# Stop long running javascript functions on the browser

Tags: javascript, function, promise

My question has two parts

1. I want to terminate a function if it runs more than 200ms and return a default value.  I tried to experiment with the concept of Promise.race but that did not yield the desired result
2. I want to identify if the function has an infinite loop similiar to how JSFiddle or Codepen is able to exit when someone uses an infinite loop without freezing the browser or overloading the CPU

Is it possible

Comment: *Is it possible* Well, since you, yourself are able to see it done on other sites, I guess the answer is "yes"?

Comment: should it be for a specific function which you can add some code or is it for all functions?

Comment: Can you just create a new promise that uses then catch on your original promise and rejects and resolves on the former wrapper function.. and also have a setTimeout race to resolve it?

Comment: Jsfiddle and codepen do it by injecting an extra counter / timeout in each and every iteration. Also the iframe'd page might run in a separate context and can be killed from  outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you can do that, here's a general-purpose script I wrote as proof of concept. It dynamically creates a web worker and uses it in the same way other languages have threads. However, if you're just trying to kill an active XHR or Fetch call, there are [built-in methods](https://davidwalsh.name/cancel-fetch) for doing that.

```js
/**
 * Run some code in it's own thread
 * @params - Any parameters you want to be passed into the thread
 * @param - The last parameter must be a function that will run in it's own thread
 * @returns - An promise-like object with a `then`, `catch`, and `abort` method
 */
function Thread() {
  var worker;
  const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var args = Array.from(arguments);
    var func = args.pop();
    if (typeof func !== "function") throw new Error("Invalid function");
    var fstr = func.toString();
    var mainBody = fstr.substring(fstr.indexOf("{") + 1, fstr.lastIndexOf("}"));
    var paramNames = fstr.substring(fstr.indexOf("(") + 1, fstr.indexOf(")")).split(",").map(p => p.trim());
    var doneFunct = paramNames.pop();
    if (paramNames.length !== args.length) throw new Error("Invalid number of arguments.");
    var workerStr = `var ${doneFunct} = function(){
            var args = Array.from(arguments);
            postMessage(args);
        };
        self.onmessage = function(d){
            var [${paramNames.join(", ")}] = d.data;
            ${mainBody}
        };`;
    var blob = new Blob([workerStr], {
      type: 'application/javascript'
    });
    worker = new Worker(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
    worker.onerror = reject;
    worker.onmessage = (d) => {
      resolve(...d.data);
      worker.terminate();
    };
    worker.postMessage(args);
  });
  return {
    then: (...params)=>promise.then(...params),
    catch: (...params)=>promise.catch(...params),
    abort: ()=>worker.terminate()
  }
}

////////////////////////
//// EXAMPLE USAGE /////
////////////////////////

// the thread will take 2 seconds to execute
// and then log the result
var myThread = new Thread("this is a message", 2, function(message, delaySeconds, exit) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    exit(message.split('').reverse().join(''));
  }, delaySeconds * 1000);
});

myThread.then(result => console.log(result));

// the thread will take 2 seconds to execute
// but we will cancel it after one second
var myThread = new Thread("this is a message", 2, function(message, delaySeconds, exit) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    exit(message.split('').reverse().join(''));
  }, delaySeconds * 1000);
});

setTimeout(()=>{
  myThread.abort();
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the function you can add a time check inside the loop that runs for long time and return when you reach time limit (simplest way, most compatible way).

If you don't know what the function is doing or can't modify it, you can try wrapping it inside a [Web worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers). If you start the long running js inside the worker, you can then .terminate() it when it reaches the timeout

Also, [It is impossible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) to determine if something contains an infinite loop without executing it